# How to reduce size (mb) of image picked from gallery

Tags: java, android

When the user selects an image from the gallery, I convert it into a base64 string. Then I use an API. The image size must be less than 2MB, so if the image from the gallery is bigger than 2MB, I need to reduce its size.
How should I do that?

That's my code:

```
// I pass the URI of the image to the method
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uris[0]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bytes = output.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Bitmap object using

[BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int))

> Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array.

and then you can use

[bitmap.compress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

> Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified
>   outputstream. If this returns true, the bitmap can be reconstructed by
>   passing a corresponding inputstream to BitmapFactory.decodeStream().
>   Note: not all Formats support all bitmap configs directly, so it is
>   possible that the returned bitmap from BitmapFactory could be in a
>   different bitdepth, and/or may have lost per-pixel alpha (e.g. JPEG
>   only supports opaque pixels).
>
> This method may take several seconds to complete, so it should only be
>   called from a worker thread.

and/or

[Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

> Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap, when possible.
>   If the specified width and height are the same as the current width
>   and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no
>   new bitmap is created.

In my project I created two utility functions that might help you understand how to use the functions I mentioned above to fit your needs

```
public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String encodedImage) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}

public static String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap, int quality, int percentScale) {
    if (quality < 0 || quality > 100) {
        quality = IMAGE_QUALITY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }
    if (percentScale < 0 || percentScale > 100) {
        percentScale = IMAGE_SCALE_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }

    float scale = (float) percentScale / 100;
    int width = Math.round(bitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    int height = Math.round(bitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to easily check the image and store it is according to the developer docs
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java
Which gives a solution to your answer explained properly and another way is to change the size of the image which can be found here and then use it accordingly
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable